# Avoid calling pages from other workspace in Oracle APEX

Tags: security, oracle-apex

In my Apex 19 server i have 2 workspaces, say WS1 with apps 100 and 101 and WS2 with apps 200 and 201.

Workspaces should have to be isolated, users shouldn't see other workspace applications, but if the user is in WS1 with the url /ws1/f?p=100:1:::::: and changes the url in /ws1/f?p=200:1::::::, he can change the workspace and is redirected to App 200 login page.

In this case i would like the user to get a 404 error.

What am i doing wrong? How do i avoid the user change the workspaces he cannot access?

Comment: Why 404? User tried to access a valid URL and Apex responded, asking user to enter credentials. User doesn't have them for that application? Good, so they won't be able to access it.

Comment: A "valid" url should be  /ws2/f?p=200:1: because page 200 belongs to ws2, not ws1. I don't want to call a page that does not belong to that workspace. If I create a workspace on apex.oracle.com and try to call a page that does not belong to my WS, i get a 404 error

Comment: That is not how apex works. The workspace is not part of the url. A user doesn't know about workspaces - that is a concept in the backend and a user shouldn't care. This is a non-issue since protecting your applications properly (as @Littlefoot said above) will ensure that only the appropriate users have access.

Answer (score 1):

You can isolate your workspace through allowed hostname option. Check the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aeadm/isolating-workspace-to-prevent-browser-attacks.html#GUID-8BF9FF41-1CA7-44E7-A82E-42B927F42CF9).